# can't get a simple counter function to work

Tags: python, function

I have looked at this piece of code over and over again and can't figure out what I am doing wrong!

```
word='banana'
def counting(x):
    count=0
    for i in word:
        if i=='a':
            count=count+1
            return count
print (counting(word))
```

The result should be `3` (`3` instances of `'a'` in `'banana'`). But the actual output is `1`. How should I fix my code?

Comment: You are returning the count before the loop is completed.

Comment: It's always a great idea to write this kind of functions yourself. However once you know how it works you should stick to functionality that is provided by python. Your function is doing exactly what `print(word.count("a"))` would do ^

Comment: Besides the actual problem already mentioned in the other posts, you're accessing the global variable `word` instead of the parameter `x` inside the function's body. This will make the function fails if used with any string that is not referred by the variable `word`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your return statement appears to be indented so as to be within the if statement within the loop.  Make sure you are not returning the count until the loop fully completes.

```py
word='banana'
def counting(x):
    count=0
    for i in x:
        if i=='a':
            count=count+1
    return count
print (counting(word))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you return `count` inside of your for loop. The first time `'a'` is found in your word, you will immediately return from  the function.

Hence why your function will always either return 0 if no char was found, or 1 if any char was found.

By the way - this logic is already built-in as a string method in python.

`count = word.count('a')`

will do the trick.